# Issue while orchestrating a Dataform Workflow through GCP Workflows

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, workflow, dataform

I'm trying to schedule Dataform executions with Workflows and Cloud Scheduler, as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/schedule-executions-workflows).

Specifically, I'm trying to customize the Dataform workflow invocation request in order to execute only those models with the 'hourly' tag, this part is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/schedule-executions-workflows#customize_the_sql_workflow_invocation_request).

The resulting YAML I have is:

```
main:
    steps:
    - init:
        assign:
        - repository: projects/XXXXX/locations/europe-west4/repositories/XXXXX
    - createCompilationResult:
        call: http.post
        args:
            url: ${"https://dataform.googleapis.com/v1beta1/" + repository + "/compilationResults"}
            auth:
                type: OAuth2
            body:
                compilationResult: ${compilationResult.body.name}                
                invocationConfig:
                    includedTags:
                    - hourly
                    transitiveDependenciesIncluded: true
        result: compilationResult
    - createWorkflowInvocation:
        call: http.post
        args:
            url: ${"https://dataform.googleapis.com/v1beta1/" + repository + "/workflowInvocations"}
            auth:
                type: OAuth2
            body:
                compilationResult: ${compilationResult.body.name}
        result: workflowInvocation
    - complete:
        return: ${workflowInvocation.body.name}
```

But I get this error when I try to deploy this workflow:

> Could not deploy workflow: failed to build: error in step
> createCompilationResult: error evaluating attribute for key 'body':
> error evaluating attribute for key 'compilationResult': symbol
> 'compilationResult.body.invocationConfig' is undefined, and symbol
> 'compilationResult.body' is undefined, and symbol 'compilationResult'
> is neither a variable nor a sub-workflow name (Code: 3)

I don't have many experience in how to solve this. I'm just following the linked documentation and apparently I'm missing something or the documentation is wrong.

Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Did you try to log the compilationResult data? Did you notice something strange or unexpected?

Comment: hey @guillaumeblaquiere I think there is some issue in the documentation, I have explained what I found in my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the documentation is wrong. I obtained what I wanted, but not following what suggested the doc [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/schedule-executions-workflows#customize_the_sql_workflow_invocation_request): The doc suggests to:

> replace the **createCompilationResult** body with the following code
> snippet...

But I actually replaced the same code snippet in the **createWorkflowInvocation**, just because it had more sense... and it worked as I expected. I think there is a Copy/Paste issue in the documentation, copying and pasting from the previous section to this one.

I'm sharing the correct YAML (at least, what worked for me):

```
main:
    steps:
    - init:
        assign:
        - repository: projects/XXXXX/locations/europe-west4/repositories/XXXXX
    - createCompilationResult:
        call: http.post
        args:
            url: ${"https://dataform.googleapis.com/v1beta1/" + repository + "/compilationResults"}
            auth:
                type: OAuth2
            body:
                gitCommitish: main                
        result: compilationResult
    - createWorkflowInvocation:
        call: http.post
        args:
            url: ${"https://dataform.googleapis.com/v1beta1/" + repository + "/workflowInvocations"}
            auth:
                type: OAuth2
            body:
                compilationResult: ${compilationResult.body.name}
                invocationConfig:
                    includedTags:
                    - hourly
                    transitiveDependenciesIncluded: true
        result: workflowInvocation
    - complete:
        return: ${workflowInvocation.body.name}
```